# Array missing in react redux reducer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

i am trying to check my inner array id same as dispatched id, table **example**

```
{
 _id :1,
 name: sagar elias jacky
 Amenities :[{ id: 100, title : hi },{ id: 101, title : hallo } ]
}
```

checking dispatched id exit or not using map,

```
return { ...state, 
  items : {...state.items, 
  Amenities : { ...state.items.Amenities
 .map(x=> x._id === action.dispatchedID ?  {...x,deleting: true} :  x ) }}}
```

but it will return with non array Amenities, like

```
Amenities:
0: { id: 100, title : hi },
1: { id: 101, title : hallo }
```

i want this to

```
Amenities:Array(2)
0: { id: 100, title : hi },
1: { id: 101, title : hallo }
```

Comment: returned array looks the same as your output, can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you spread an array inside `{}`, it creates an object with indexes of array as `keys`

```js
const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}]
console.log({...array})
```

So, change

```
Amenities : { ...state.items.Amenities
 .map(x=> x._id === action.dispatchedID ?  {...x,deleting: true} :  x ) }
```

to:

```
Amenities : [ ...state.items.Amenities
 .map(x=> x._id === action.dispatchedID ?  {...x,deleting: true} :  x ) ]
```